# Parse JSON containing "\u as UTF-8 bytes" in Python

Tags: python, json, unicode

I have a JSON file from the Facebook's "Download your data" feature and instead of escaping Unicode characters as their codepoint number, it's escaped just as a sequence of UTF-8 bytes.

For example, the letter á (U+00E1) is escaped in the JSON file as `\u00c3\u00a1` instead of `\u00e1`. 0xC3 0xA1 is UTF-8 encoding for U+00E1.

The `json` library in Python 3 decodes it as Ã¡ which corresponds to U+00C3 and U+00A1.

Is there a way to parse such a file correctly (so that I get the letter á) in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems they encoded their Unicode string into bytes using utf-8 then transformed the bytes into JSON. This is very bad behaviour from them.

Python 3 example:

```
>>> '\u00c3\u00a1'.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
'á'
```

You need to parse the JSON and walk the entire data to fix it:

```
def visit_list(l):
    return [visit(item) for item in l]

def visit_dict(d):
    return {visit(k): visit(v) for k, v in d.items()}

def visit_str(s):
    return s.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')

def visit(node):
    funcs = {
        list: visit_list,
        dict: visit_dict,
        str: visit_str,
    }
    func = funcs.get(type(node))
    if func:
        return func(node)
    else:
        return node

incorrect = '{"foo": ["\u00c3\u00a1", 123, true]}'
correct_obj = visit(json.loads(incorrect))
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the string is loaded from a file, the string in that case is `'\\u00c3\\u00a1'`.

Comment: what do you mean "it doesn't work"? does the string contain literal backslashes? if it does, you can use `json.loads` on them to parse this notation, or alternatively `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: The `\u00c3\u00a1` I mentioned in the question is how it's saved in the JSON file itself, that means when I look at the file in a text editor, I see exactly that (Python wasn't involved at that point). So yes, both the file and the string loaded from it contain literal backslashes. But when I use `json.loads` it's parsed incorrectly into Ã¡

Comment: you need to fix the whole data _after_ parsing. i just edited my answer to add code to show how to fix it.